# $(-1)^2$ in $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

In p-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_p$, $-1=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(p-1)p^i$, but when I take square of $-1$ $\mathbb{Q}_p$, I am getting $1+2p+3p^2...$. Shouldn't it be $1$ as we are squaring $-1$? The product that I used is the usual convolution. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how you got that?

Comment: Didn't you forget $(p-1)^2$?

Comment: Oh, the mistake I was doing, I was taking modulo p everytime. That is how I got that answer. Instead I should have arranged the sum properly Got it..